# Can't figure out why this loop is a data race

Tags: go

I have a loop that is apparently causing a data race its near the bottom of this function and I will have it marked:

```
func (p *PartialParty) SendReadyCheck(party PartialParty) {
    msg, err := json.Marshal(&ReadyCheckMsg{"ReadyCheck", ""})
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    for _, member := range party.Members {
        member.Conn.send <- msg
    }

    counter := 0
    loopBreaker := true
    for {
        select {
        case <-p.Accept:
            counter++
            resp, err := json.Marshal(&ReadyCheckMsg{"ReadyAccepted", ""})
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
            }
            for _, member := range party.Members {
                member.Conn.send <- resp
            }
            if counter == 2 {
                // Create a new party with all members
                partyid := PartyID(feeds.NewUUID().String())
                db := common.Db()
                newParty := &Party{
                    Active:    true,
                    Members:   p.Members,
                    Broadcast: make(chan []byte),
                    PartyID:   partyid,
                }

                // Insert the new party into the database
                _, err := db.Exec("INSERT INTO party SET party_id = ?, active = ?", partyid.String(), true)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Println(err)
                }

                // Go through the members and update the database
                var wg sync.WaitGroup

                for _, member := range party.Members {
                    wg.Add(1)
                    m := member
                    go func() {
                        _, err := db.Exec("UPDATE party_members SET active = ? WHERE steamid = ?", false, m.SteamID)
                        if err != nil {
                            log.Println(err)
                        }
                        _, err = db.Exec("INSERT INTO party_members SET belongs_to =?, active = ?, steamid = ?", partyid.String(), true, m.SteamID)
                        if err != nil {
                            log.Println(err)
                        }
                        wg.Done()
                    }()
                }

                // Wait for all the database stuff to finish
                wg.Wait()
                PHub.AddNewParty(newParty)
                loopBreaker = false
                break
            }
        case conn := <-p.Decline:
            if conn.Ready {
                break
            }
            conn.Ready = false
            conn.InQueue = false
            conn.CurrentParty = ""
            resp, err := json.Marshal(&ReadyCheckMsg{"ReadyCheckDeclined", ""})
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
            }
            p.Accepting = true
            identifier := conn.Identifier
            if _, ok := party.Members[identifier]; ok {
                delete(p.Members, identifier)
            }
            for _, m := range party.Members {
                member := m
                member.Conn.send <- resp
            }
            log.Println("Here")
            loopBreaker = false
            break
        case <-time.After(30 * time.Second):
            if counter == 2 {
                return
            }
            p.Accepting = true
            failedMsg, err := json.Marshal(&ReadyCheckMsg{"FailedToReady", ""})
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
            }
            somebodyDeclinedMsg, err := json.Marshal(&ReadyCheckMsg{"ReadyCheckDeclined", ""})
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
            }


    >>>>     for _, member := range party.Members { ***<<<< This Line***
                m := member
                if !m.Conn.Ready {
                    m.Conn.Ready = false
                    m.Conn.InQueue = false
                    m.Conn.CurrentParty = ""
                    m.Conn.send <- failedMsg
                } else {
                    m.Conn.Ready = false
                    m.Conn.send <- somebodyDeclinedMsg
                }
            }
            loopBreaker = false
            break
        }
        if !loopBreaker {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

It is apparently conflicting with this:

```
// AddNewMember will add a new user to the party
func (p *PartyHub) AddNewMember(member *Member, partyid PartyID) {
    p.Lock()
    defer p.Unlock()
>>> p.PartialPartys[partyid].Members[member.Conn.Identifier] = member
}

type PartialParty struct {
    Accepting bool
    Members   map[Identifier]*Member
    Accept    chan *Connection
    Decline   chan *Connection
    PartyID   PartyID
    sync.Mutex
}
```

Right now it is impossible to `AddNewMember` if the goroutine `SendReadyCheck`  is running ``because it is protected by an if statement that checks if the goroutine is running, so I'm not sure why they are saying they are racing each other. Any help on clearing this up would be great. I've tried setting a variable inside the loop to try to get away from it but it doesn't seem to cause it

Answer (score 0):

> Right now it is impossible to AddNewMember if the goroutine SendReadyCheck is running ``because it is protected by an if statement that checks if the goroutine is running

You didn't actually show that part of the code, but presumably it's not impossible. What if SendReadyCheck starts running *after* the if test but before AddNewMember does its modification?